# How to get whole pdf files from iOS internal storage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to list all pdf files from whole internal storage in my flutter app in android works fine but for iOS it's not support.

I used path_provider package.

But in this package there is no support for iOS.

Thanks in advance for any help :}
Officially by path_provider it's not support for iOS but i need to also access whole internal storage directory files path...
I try this code:

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllPdfFilesFromStorage() async {
    // Get the root directory of the device's storage
    Directory? root;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      root = Directory('storage/emulated/0/');
    } else {
      root = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      // final Directory? downloadsDir = await getDownloadsDirectory();

      print("Root is::::::::::::${root}");
      // print("Root is::::::::::::${downloadsDir}");
    }

    // Create a list to store all PDF files and their names
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> pdfFiles = [];

    // Recursively search for PDF files in all directories
    await searchForPdfFiles(root!, pdfFiles);

    // Return the list of PDF files, their names, and their sizes
    return pdfFiles;
  }

  Future<void> searchForPdfFiles(Directory dir, List<Map<String, dynamic>> pdfFiles) async {
    // Get all files and directories in the current directory
    List<FileSystemEntity> entities = dir.listSync();
    print("mammmm::::::::::${entities}");

    // Iterate over each entity and check if it's a file or a directory
    for (FileSystemEntity entity in entities) {
      print("mammmm::::::::::${entity.path}");

      if (entity is File) {
        print("mammmm::::::::::${entity.path}");
        // Check if the file is a PDF file
        if (entity.path.endsWith('.pdf')) {
          // Add the PDF file, its name, and its size to the list
          pdfFiles.add({
            'file': entity,
            'name': entity.path.split('/').last,
            'size': await entity.length(),
          });
        }
      } else if (entity is Directory) {
        print("mammmm::::::::::${entity.path}");

        // Recursively search for PDF files in the subdirectory
        await searchForPdfFiles(entity, pdfFiles);
      }
      print("mammmm::::::::::${entity.path}");
    }
  }

  mainTest() async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.request();

    if (status.isGranted) {
      kDocController.localPdfFiles.value = await getAllPdfFilesFromStorage();
      print(kDocController.localPdfFiles);
      // The OS restricts access, for example because of parental controls.
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getId();
    // getPdfFilesFromStorage();
    // print(getPdf());
    mainTest();
    // List<File> pdfFiles = await getPdf();

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code with the error log ?

Comment: Sure i will update my question

Comment: Officially this package not support iOS external storage

Comment: for iOS, root = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path or root = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path